# Haskell List functions

Tags: haskell

I was wondering why in Haskell there are not symmetry in some function names:

For example:

- `head` : get the first element
- `last` : get the last element

Is there good reason why for example `head` function was not named `first`, or the other way around - `last` function could be named `end` or something similar.

Comment: Actually the `head` is related to `tail`, just like `last` is related to `init`. Because a list is a *linked list*, so the names are symmetrical, but the "couples" are different.

Comment: Why on earth do we want to close so many questions ?! Yes, the answer might not be clear cut but the answer shows that this is an interesting topic.

Comment: @CedricH. In this case, I agree. While some questions of the form "Why is X named like that?" are too speculative to be properly answerable in this format, this specific question is fine. It asks about well established names and concepts, with plenty of sources to back up claims like those in Willem's answer. I once wrote [a Meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/337663/2751851) explaining a bit further my views on the general issue.

Comment: I always correlated it for head/tail as in coins, but I'm most likely wrong.

Comment: Lists in Haskell are single-link lists. In a singly linked list, using the last element requires a full traversal of the length. length is also very expensive because of single links to the end of the list. Haskell lists are made for reading from the beginning, like a novel.

Answer (score 8):

Haskell's function has two couples of list functions:

1. `head :: [a] -> a`, and `tail :: [a] -> [a]`; and
2. `init :: [a] -> [a]` and `last :: [a] -> a`.

[*Learn You a Haskell for the Greater Good*](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out) made a nice illustration about this:

[image]

The `head` thus is the first element of the list, whereas the `tail` is the list that contains the remaining elements.

The `init` takes all the elements except the last one, and `last` thus takes the last element.

A list in Haskell is a conceptually a *linked* list. Usually random access is not very common in list processing. Usually most list processing functions take a list and processes this like a stream of items.

It is common [nomenclature of linked lists [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Basic_concepts_and_nomenclature) to specify:

> The **`head` of a list is its first node**. The **`tail`** of a list may refer either to the **rest of the list after the head**, or to the last node in the list. In Lisp and some derived languages, the next node may be called the `cdr` (pronounced could-er) of the list, while the payload of the head node may be called the `car`.

Comment: Yes, but my point is why they called it "head", isnt more correct to call it "first" ?

Comment: @user2693928: well this is common terminology about linked lists: https://www.cpp.edu/~ftang/courses/CS240/lectures/slist.htm

Comment: Thanks, now I understand why :)

Comment: @user2693928 "Head" is a pretty well established English word for the front end of things  - "the head of the queue" for instance.

Comment: @user2693928 Haskell defines a function `fst (x,y) = x` which however works on pairs, not lists. The designers could have named `head` as `first`, but it would read aloud in the same way.